# HTTP Post Response After a cURL command

Tags: curl

Thanks for your help.

I want to fill a form with a CURL command line command. 
My form test is very simple, a user text input, and a Birthday Date text input with a Submit button.

When i run the command :

`curl --data "user=me&birthday=2003/12/12&btnSubmit=Submit" http://www.myurl.com`

After that, I receive the html page and not the response page who normally show a blank page with name : name
birthday : birthday

Manually, my page is work well, when I click Submit button, I see the result page appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also add the `-X POST` with your curl commandline so that it posts the data to the url.

Comment: Thanks for your support. In fact, I tried it but I have the same issue, I only receive the HTML code of the page of my form and not the result page that normally must appear...

Comment: Didn't get what you mean. Can I have an example? If its http status code like `301`, `302`, etc, then also add `-L` option with curl to handle redirection.

Comment: It's Weird because I haven't get any error message, and the CURL response Header is like : `* Connected to --------------- port 80 (#0)
> POST ------------------ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: ------------
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1097
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Length: 437355
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5 is not blacklisted
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
`

Comment: After, follow the HTML code of my form page. Not the right HTML Response page I normally have when I submit this form manually into a browser.