# regex and grep match only string with valid port in an if loop

Tags: regex, bash, while-loop, grep, port

I'm trying to check in a bash script if a curl response I'm getting is giving me a valid IANA port. If it is, then I want to break the loop and continue on.  If it gives me no port, then I want it to delete the file and try again after a sleep period.

My problem is the grep and regex query.  I'm still learning regex and not sure if I got this right. Can anyone verify it. (or propose an easier solution to the same problem.

```
port_forwarding_assignment=/home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt
while [ ! -f "$port_forwarding_assignment" ]; do    
    sudo curl -d "post_data_stuff" https://website/port_forward_assignment -o "/home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt"

    if [grep -q '^Port (6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)$' "$port_forwarding_assignment"]; then
        break
    fi

    rm -f /home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt
    sleep 30  
done
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to check if the port number is within a certain range or something of that sort. That is not really what regex was designed for. Instead, you can extract the number portion from the string, convert to int and then check if that int is in a certain range. Hope that helps

Comment: Could you add a post response? E.g. here I see a response with "port" in stead of "Port"; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005512/http-post-response-after-a-curl-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of comments on the code:

- The `[` character in bash is actually shorthand for the builtin `test` command, so you should have a space after it. Thus: `if [ ...`.
- But `if` tests the return code of its argument, so you really do not want to write `[ grep`. Instead, just write: `if grep -q ...` to test the return code from `grep`.
- To use repetition in grep, you either need to use `-E` or write `\{...\}` (or use `egrep` as short for `grep -E`).
- You can use pipes instead of storing the output in a file. But then you need to handle the case that `curl` returns an error, possibly with `PIPESTATUS`.
- Not sure why you need `sudo` for this.

A rewrite according to the first 3 comments:

```
port_forwarding_assignment=/home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt
while [ ! -f "$port_forwarding_assignment" ]; do    
    sudo curl -d "post_data_stuff" https://website/port_forward_assignment -o "/home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt"

    if grep -qE '^Port (6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)$' "$port_forwarding_assignment"; then
        break
    fi

    rm -f /home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt
    sleep 30  
done
```

Since you are not checking the return code from `curl` anyway, you could also change according to my 4th comment. Code after all five comments have been applied:

```
port_forwarding_assignment=/home/user/port_forwarding_assignment.txt
while ! curl -d "post_data_stuff" https://website/port_forward_assignment |
  tee "$port_forwarding_assignment" |
  grep -qE '^Port (6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)$'
do
    sleep 30  
done
```